# Python and BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've gotten to the point where I have the HTML, but I'd like to extract just one string out of it

There is a line in each HTML file that looks like this

```
<h4 class="ws-ds-name detail-title">DATA_I_WANT</h4>
```

And I'm not sure how to use the .find() method to get exactly that tag and then extract out the DATA_I_WANT

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
markup = ''' some HTML here '''
soup = bs(markup)
soup.find('h4', {'class':'ws-ds-name detail-title'}).contents[0]
# result: 
# u'DATA_I_WANT'
```

Or you could use lxml:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
doc = fromstring(markup)
doc.xpath('//h4[@class="ws-ds-name detail-title"]')[0].text
# result: 
# 'DATA_I_WANT'
```

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'.  The initial find is returning a NoneType, but I'm quite sure that the line looks like that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to work on my machine (using BS and lxml). Maybe someone else will know what the problem could be. Good luck.

Comment: @Arjun: Adam's code looks fine. Please show us the HTML markup that causes the AttributeError.